# Showing that for a subgroup $H \subset G$ of a linear algebraic group $G$, the closure $\overline{H} \subset G$ is a subgroup.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-groups

*Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $K$ and $H \subset G$ be a subgroup. Denote by $\overline{H}$ the closure of $H$ in $G$ with respect to the Zariski-topology on $G$. I now want to show, that $\overline{H} \subset G$ is a subgroup and hence a linear algebraic group.*

---

**Idea:**

We have $H \subset G$ and the closure $\overline{H}$ is by definition the smallest closed subset of $G$ that contains $H$, so in particular $\overline{H} \subseteq G$ (as subset). Also since, $H \subset \overline{H}$, we have that $\overline{H}$ is non-empty.

My problem now is that I don't know how to prove that this is actually a group.

**Edit:**
In order for $\overline{H}$ to be a subgroup, we have to show that $\overline{H} \overline{H}^{-1} \subseteq \overline{H}$. Let $f: G \times G \to G$, $f(x,y)=xy^{-1}$ be the multiplication (with inversion) in $G$. By orangeskid´s answer below, this map is continious. Hence $f^{-1}(\overline{H})$ is closed. Furthermore we have $H \times H \subset f^{-1}(\overline{H})$ and taking closures $\overline{H \times H} \subset f^{-1}(\overline{H})$. Then left to show is
$$\overline{H} \times \overline{H} \subset \overline{H \times H}.$$
This would finally imply, that
$$f(\overline{H} \times \overline{H}) = \overline{H} \overline{H}^{-1} \subseteq \overline{H}.$$
So now i´m stuck showing $\overline{H} \times \overline{H} \subset \overline{H \times H}$. Is this way ok?

Comment: Instead of editing this question, you should ask a new one for clarity. This is so that you don't move the goalposts for existing answers.

Comment: Again, you have edited the question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G$ with the Zariski topology is not a topological group, but certainly a [semitopological group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitopological_group), that is: the multiplication is separately continuous, and moreover, the inverse is continuous. For such a group, the closure of a subgroup is again a subgroup. Note that we are dealing with the Zariski closure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i tried applying it, but i´m still stuck at one point.